# Why hasn't the java-version variable the same value in my properties' and in my build files?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In order to populate my Spring Boot's Actuator with additional info, I started adding keys to my `application.properties` like this:

```
java-version=@java.version@
```

After further reading, I decided I want to rely on the auto-configured `BuildInfoContributor`/`BuildProperties` which expose the info available in the `/META-INF/build-info.properties` file:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-application-info-build
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-build.html#howto-build-info

As in my `pom.xml` I have these properties

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

then I added the extra `<additionalProperties>` to this plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalProperties>
                            <java.source>${java.version}</java.source>
                            <encoding.source>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding.source>
                            <encoding.reporting>${project.reporting.outputEncoding}</encoding.reporting>
                        </additionalProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

After the Maven build my /META-INF/build-info.properties has these add. properties amongst others:

```
build.java.source=1.8
build.encoding.reporting=UTF-8
build.encoding.source=UTF-8
```

However in my `application.properties` the value is computed as:

```
java-version=1.8.0_212
```

- How is it possible?
- Where does the `@java.version@` value come from then, if not from the project's `pom.xml`?
- How to get this *full* version of Java in my `build-info.properties` (if possible)?

I'm using Apache Maven 3.6.1

Comment: It may also help for you to generate your ["effective POM"](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) which will flatten out the inheritance etc. so you can have a clearer view of what you're actually running, and what properties are present.

Comment: I edited my post because the actual @-ed variable is indeed `@java.version@` (with a *dot* not a *dash*).

Comment: Fair enough. The property is presumably overriden then. Checking the effective POM will show you

Comment: I checked the effective POM, no override. This property appears simply as `<java.version>1.8</java.version>` in the `<properties>` tag.

Comment: Huh... I wonder whether something - a plugin? maven itself? - is "helpfully" overriding it. Try introducing a level of indirection `<maxxyme>1.8</maxxyme><java.version>${maxxyme}</java.version>` and then use `@maxxyme@` in your properties. Not a great solution but hopefully functional at least

Comment: Doesn't change anything (still **1.8** in effective POM, and **1.8.0_212** in application.properties). But in fact, I wanted the other way round, having the full version to populate my build info.

Comment: It could be related to the order in which things are happening. Your filtered resources are copied over at (I think) the process-resources phase. This spring plugin binds to the generate-resources phase by default (i.e. build-info is generated earlier). You could explicitly run the spring plugin later in the lifecycle. `prepare-package` might be a good logical option.